# How to create animated chart (moving plot) using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, plot, charts

I need to create animated chart with moving camera without using any jquery plugin. I need to write code from scratch, I can use only jquery, no plugins.

I had managed to write code that draws chart. The only problem is how to move viewport (camera) simultaneously with chart?

I understand that I need to use `translate` method. But I don't how to use it correctly.

Idea of chart that I need to create:

[image: example of chart]

Link to codepen:
http://codepen.io/sigmaray/pen/EyKNmK

My code:

```
$(function() {
  // Settings
  CAN_WIDTH = 300;
  CAN_HEIGHT = 300;
  CAN_COLOR = "#ccc";
  LINE_HEIGHT = 1;
  INTERVAL = 50;
  $DIV = $("#container");

  lineX = 0;
  lineY = CAN_HEIGHT / 2;
  ctx = null;

  randomNum = function(max, min) {
    if (min == null) {
      min = 0;
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  };

  createCanvas = function() {
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = CAN_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = CAN_HEIGHT;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    $DIV.append(canvas);
  };

  timerAnimation = function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, INTERVAL);
  };

  anim = function() {
    if (lineX > CAN_WIDTH) {
      lineX = 0;
    }
    if (lineX === 0) {
      ctx.fillStyle = CAN_COLOR;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, CAN_WIDTH, CAN_HEIGHT);
    }
    oldLineX = lineX;
    oldLineY = lineY;
    lineY = randomNum(CAN_HEIGHT * (2 / 3), CAN_HEIGHT / 3);
    xOffset = randomNum(10, 1);
    lineX += xOffset;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = LINE_HEIGHT;
    ctx.moveTo(oldLineX, oldLineY);
    ctx.lineTo(lineX, lineY);
    ctx.stroke();

    // !!! Doesn't work as expected !!!
    // ctx.translate(xOffset, 0)
    // ctx.save();
  };

  drawingCycle = function() {
    anim();
    timerAnimation(drawingCycle);
  };

  createCanvas();
  drawingCycle();
});
```

Comment: You can remove existing animation. And then try refreshing chart with new random(for test now) data every 100 ms. Chart will look like moving

Comment: `ctx.translate` does not move any existing drawings on the canvas. Canvas movement works by erasing the canvas and redrawing the chart with its new data points and with it's new offsetX. Also, `ctx.translate` is cumulative so be sure to reverse any translations you do.